# When i try to add custom method to object prototype i get error

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I wanted to add custom method on my object prototype in typescript

```
 Object.prototype['someMethodForObject'] = function() {
      console.log('do something ');
    }
```

after that i get

`value.match is not a function at WebAnimationsStyleNormalizer.normalizeStyleValue (browser.js:2008)`

but when i try to do the same thing with `String` then it works - i get no errors

```
String.prototype['someMethodForString'] = function (length: number) {
      console.log('do something');
    };
```

why is this ? How can i add method to my Object prototype ?

Comment: `tring` will not work, you're missing an `S`. `value.match is not a function` doesn't make sense as an error message either, you're not using `.match` anywhere..?

Comment: IT IS TYPE ERROR IN MY PASTING.I edited the question.In my code String works, but whe n itry to add method on Object then it does not work.I know that it does not make any sense it is something related to typescript...

Comment: `value.match is not a function at WebAnimationsStyleNormalizer.normalizeStyleValue (browser.js:2008)` is a JavaScript error, not a TypeScript error

Comment: Are you sure the error is related adding a method to `Object.prototype`?

Comment: Your code is working for me. I think you're seeing some other error not related to your code.

Comment: No, when i comment the code i get no error in my angular project.The same thing works in PURE JS but not in TYPESCRIPT.

Comment: Also, please never extend `Object.prototype` (other than testing, polyfilling, and having fun by breaking JS), especially with an enumerable property!!! It will "magically appear" on *every* `for..in` loop (regardless of *what* are you iterating over!), which is surely not what you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally adding to prototypes of JS global constructors is a bad idea. There might be code in "WebAnimationStyleNormalizer" (not sure what that is anyways) that is doing something like `for (const value in obj)` and since obj is an object and inherits `Object`'s prototype, suddenly your `someMethodForObject` is in that loop.

Take for example the following code

```js
const obj = { a: 5 }

for (const value in obj) {
  console.log(value)
}
```

will log "a".

Where

```js
Object.prototype.test = function() { }
const obj = { a: 5 }

for (const value in obj) {
  console.log(value)
}
```

will now log
"a" and then "test".

As far as why this is working for you in JS but not TS, I can't be for sure without more information. I'd imagine there is a library in your TS code doing a for..in loop on an object which is causing this error.